# Call a PHP function by concatenation

Tags: php

How can I call a PHP function by concatenating a string and variable to form the function name?

Here's what I'm trying to do, but it won't work. I know there's `call_user_func()`, but I'm trying to avoid that.

```
$val = 'user'; //varies, can be active, subscribed, unsubscribed etc.

'fetch_'.$val($val);

function fetch_user($users) {
    echo 'Function was called';
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `call_user_func()`?

Answer (score 2):

Storing it in a variable and then executing it is an possibility:

```
$val = 'user'; //varies, can be active, subscribed, unsubscribed etc.

$function = 'fetch_'.$val;

function fetch_user($users) {
    echo 'Function was called with ' . $users;
}

$function($val);
```

result:

```
Function was called with user
```

Comment: Yes, possible, but a _horrible_ style.